# A question for Cauchy matrix $C= \left[\frac{1}{x_i+y_j}\right]$.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Let $C= \left[\frac{1}{x_i+y_j}\right]$, where $0<x_1<\cdots<x_n$ and $0<y_1<\cdots<y_n$ are positive real numbers. Then $C$ is called a Cauchy matrix of order $n$. We know that this matrix is totally positive, i.e., all its minors are positive. To prove this, we first prove 
(a). $\det C\neq 0$ for every choice of $0<x_1<\cdots<x_n$ and $0<y_1<\cdots<y_n$. This I understood. 
(b). Then we say that $\det C$ is a continuous function of variables $0<x_1,\ldots,x_n$ and $0<y_1,\ldots,y_n$. Hence by Intermediate Value Theorem, $\det C$ is either positive or negative for all $0<x_1<\cdots<x_n$ and $0<y_1<\cdots<y_n$. I have a confusion in this part (b).

I know that (b) is trying to say that if we have $0<a_1<\cdots<a_n$, $0<b_1<\cdots<b_n$ where $\det C$ is positive and $0<c_1<\cdots<c_n$,$0<d_1<\cdots<d_n$, where $\det C$ is negative, then by IVT, there exist points $0<e_1<\cdots<e_n$, $0<f_1<\cdots<f_n$, where $\det C=0$, which is not possible. But why should these $e_i$'s and $f_j$'s be in increasing order?

Any help please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use notation $u=(u_1,u_2,\ldots, u_n)$ for $0<u_1<u_2<\ldots <u_n.$
Assume $$\det C_{x^{(0)},y^{(0)}}>0,\qquad \det C_{x^{(1)},y^{(1)}}<0$$
Let $$x^{(t)}=(1-t)x^{(0)}+tx^{(1)},\qquad y^{(t)}=(1-t)y^{(0)}+ty^{(1)}$$
Then $$f(t)=\det C_{x^{(t)},y^{(t)}},\qquad 0\le t\le 1$$
is continuous and $f(0)>0, $ $f(1)<0.$ Thus $f(t)=0$ for some $0<t<1.$ The sequences
$x^{(t)}$ and $y^{(t)}$ are increasing as convex combinations of increasing sequences $x^{(0)}$ and $x^{(1)}, $ $y^{(0)}$ and $y^{(1)},$ respectively.

Concerning a proof of (a), consider the space $L^2(0,1)$ and functions $f_i(t)=t^{x_i-1/2}$ and
$g_j(t)=t^{y_j-1/2}.$ Then
$$\langle f_i,g_j\rangle =\int\limits_0^1 t^{x_i+y_j-1}\,dt ={1\over x_i+y_j}$$
Therefore $$C=\{\langle f_i, g_j\rangle \}_{i,j=1}^n$$
Any matrix of this form is invertible, i.e. $\det C\neq 0$ provided that the functions $\{f_i\}_{i=1}^n$ are linearly independent as well as $\{g_j\}_{j=1}^n$ are linearly independent.

We will show that $\{t^{\alpha_i-1/2}\}_{i=1}^n$ are linearly independent in $L^2(0,1)$ for $0<\alpha_1<\ldots <\alpha_n.$ Assume $$\lambda_1t^{\alpha_1-1/2}+\lambda_2t^{\alpha_2-1/2}+\ldots +\lambda_n t^{\alpha_n-1/2}=0$$ Then
$$t^{\alpha_1-1/2}[\lambda_1+\lambda_2t^{\alpha_2-\alpha_1}+\ldots +\lambda_n t^{\alpha_n-\alpha_1}]=0$$ Thus
$$\lambda_1+\lambda_2t^{\alpha_2-\alpha_1}+\ldots +\lambda_n t^{\alpha_n-\alpha_1}=0,\ a.e.$$ As the function is continuous in $[0,1]$ we get
$$\lambda_1+\lambda_2t^{\alpha_2-\alpha_1}+\ldots +\lambda_n t^{\alpha_n-\alpha_1}=0,\ 0\le t\le 1$$
Plugging in $t=0$ gives $\lambda_1=0,$ i.e. we are reduced to $n-1$ functions. Therefore  the induction argument completes the proof.

It suffices to show that $C=\{\langle u_i,v_j\rangle \}_{i,j=1}^n$ satisfies $\det C\neq 0$ for any linearly independent collections $\{u_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{v_j\}_{j=1}^n$ in some inner product space. Observe that replacing $u_i$ by $$\tilde{u}_i=u_i-\sum_{k\neq i}\lambda_k u_k $$ does not change the determinant, and the linear indpendence is preserved. The same is valid for $$\tilde{v}_j=v_j-\sum_{k\neq j}\lambda_k v_k $$
Therefore by the Gram-Schmidt procedure we can assume that
$$C=\{\langle \tilde{u}_i,\tilde{v}_j\rangle \}_{i,j=1}^n$$ and the collections $\{\tilde{u}_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{\tilde{v}_j\}_{j=1}^n$ consist of orthogonal elements.
Thus $$\tilde{u}_i=\|\tilde{u}_i\|\,\hat{u}_i,\qquad \tilde{v}_j=\|\tilde{v}_j\|\,\hat{v}_j$$
where the collections $\{\hat{u}_i\}_{i=1}^n$ and $\{\hat{v}_j\}_{j=1}^n$ consist of orthonormal elements.
Then
$$\det C=\prod_{i=1}^n\|\tilde{u}_i\|\,\prod_{j=1}^n\|\tilde{v}_i\|\ \det\{\langle \hat{u}_i,\hat{v}_j\rangle\}_{i,j=1}^n$$
The matrix $\hat{C}=\langle \hat{u}_i,\hat{v}_j\rangle\}_{i,j=1}^n$ is orthogonal as a transition matrix between two orthonormal systems (with real entries). Hence $\det\hat{C}=\pm 1,$ and consequently $\det C\neq 0.$

Comment: thanks a lot! I wonder if I prove that the part (a) is true for all positive real numbers $0<x_1<\cdots<x_n$ and $0<y_1<\cdots<y_n$ such that $y_{i+1}-y_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $i$, then will it be sufficient to prove that $\det C$ preserve the sign. I know that we can't apply here IVP because the corresponding space won't be connected. Any hint/help/comment regarding this please.

Comment: If $y_{i+1}-y_i \in \mathbb{Z}$ for all $i$, then will the function $f(t)$ defined by you be continuous on $[0,1]$?

Comment: If you prove part (a) for $\mathbb{Z},$ then it will be true for rational values of $x_i$ and $y_j.$ But it will not imply all positive values. The function $f(t)$ is rational with denominators, which are products of $(1-t)x_i+ty_j.$ That's why it is continuous. I thought you managed to get part (a).

Comment: I think part (a) can be proved by applying sort of Gram matrix. Shall I extend my answer ?

Comment: Do you mean, $f(t)$ is a sum of rational functions, where each rational function has a denominator, which is a product of $(1-t)x^{(t)}_i+ty^{(t)}_j$? Now, since $x^{(t)}_i$ and $y^{(t)}_j$ are continuous for every $i$ and $j$, the function $f(t)$ is also continuous on $[0,1]$. Is it correct? If yes, then why can't $f(t)$ be continuous when $y_{i+1}-y_{i} \in \mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: If I am right, you have constructed a continuous path $C_{x^{(t)},y^{(t)}}$ joining two matrices $C_{x^{(0)},y^{(0)}}$ and $C_{x^{(1)},y^{(1)}}$. Can we make a continuous path joining the same provided $y^{(t)}_{i+1}-y^{(t)}_i \in \mathbb{Z^+}$ for all $t \in [0,1]$ ?

Comment: Consider $n=2$ and $y_1^{(0)}=1,$ $y_2^{(0)}=2,$ $y_1^{(1)}=1$ and $y_2^{(1)}=3.$ Then $y_2^{(0)} -y_1^{(0)}=1$ and $y_2^{(1)} -y_1^{(1)}=2.$ It is not possible to move continuously from $1$ to $2$ so that the difference stay integer. Besides, why do you care for integer values of the differences ?

Comment: Actually, I have a problem given in the assignment. So I was curious. Also, sorry I forgot to mention that $y^{(t)}_{(i+1)}-y^{(t)}_i = \alpha$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, where $\alpha$ is a fixed positive integer. Can we have a positive answer now?

Comment: You mean you start with sequences $y^{(0)}$ and $y^{(1)}$ so that $y_{i+1}^{(0)}-y_{i}^{(0)}=a$ and $y_{i+1}^{(1)}-y_{i}^{(1)}=a$ for all $i.$ Then $y_{i+1}^{(t)}-y_{i}^{(t)}=a$  just by applying the formula for $y^{(t)}.$

Comment: Yes Sir. Is it correct!

Comment: @Szwarc, is this statement correct.

Comment: Which statement ?

Comment: your last statement was "you mean you start with sequences........." Do you agree with it?

Comment: It is correct. If $y_{i+1}^{(0)}-y_{i}^{(0)}=a$ and  $y_{i+1}^{(1)}-y_{i}^{(1)}=a$ then $y_{i+1}^{(t)}-y_{i}^{(t)}=a$

Comment: it means if I prove the (a) part for all positive increasing $x_i$ and $y_j$ such that $y_{j+1}-y_j$ is a constant positive integer, then part (b) will also hold for such $x_i$ and $y_j$?

Comment: Yes, but the statement is true in general, without the  assumption that the difference is constant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137342/discussion-between-prince-and-ryszard-szwarc).